# How to specify path to mySQL using localhost?

Tags: java, mysql, path, xampp, localhost

I have been having issues specifying the path (I have two files: comments.frm and db.opt in the following folder: C:\xampp\mysql\data\feedback)... I am using XAMPP and mySQL. I am not sure why I am having an error? Please, take a look this part of my code:

```
public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
   try {
        // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
    connect = DriverManager
         .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost//feedback"
              + "user=root&password=1234");
```

PS: My password for localhost is 12345678

Comment: The connection string will be wrong since you are concatenating `user` to `feedback`: `jdbc:mysql://localhost//feedbackuser=root&password=1234`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback", "root", "1234");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 connect = DriverManager
     .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?user=root&password=1234")
```

(you forgot about the question mark after "feedback")

Answer (score 2):

For better clarity you can use the other overloaded method while getting connection.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<db_ip>/<db_name>", 
    "<username>", "<pwd>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feedback", "root", "1234");
```

I check my old project and find that I don't use double slash here `/feedback`.

also you can specify encoding like this :

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feedback?characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterEncoding=Cp1251", "root", "1234");
```

and also one more advice. Don't use hard code. Get url, password and user name from property files.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this hope it can help you!!!**

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"+"user=root&password=1234");
```

---

also see the URL Mistakes like:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost//feedback?

// after localhost... check and try my code...
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers but everyone forgot the port of the database.

If you use mysql then try 3306 as db port.
http://www.petefreitag.com/articles/jdbc_urls/ - list of jdbc urls (Examples)

```
try 
{ 
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName, user, passwd); 
} 
catch(SQLException sqle) 
{ 
    System.out.println("Connection fails: " + sqle.getMessage()); 
}
```